# Installation of NPM package fails with unrelated package error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, npm, package-managers

I execute this command on my node app:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

and I get this error:

```
> libpq@1.8.8 install /Users/prmph/Dropbox/Repositories/Alt/node_modules/libpq
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: pg_config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

What has typescript got to do with pg_config?

I do have some Postgres related package in my package.json, but why would installing a specific package have anything to do with packages already installed

Comment: Would you mind sharing some more of your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

When installing a new package `npm` will also install missing packages from `package.json`

Try to start from a clean state before installing your new package.

Comment: Even if I remove _./node_modules_ and run `npm install` the problem still occurs

Comment: Yes, you are missing required command in your PATH, please check package README for required dependencies. [ref](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/223#issuecomment-17557832)

Comment: > You need libpq installed & the `pg_config` program should be in your path. You also need `node-gyp` installed. https://github.com/brianc/node-libpq#install